# Unable to compile 'syllable-5.0.0' (tar.gz) because node is not 12+

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, java, nodejs

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to install a syllable counting program from source.

Ref: https://github.com/words/syllable

From `readme.md`

> This package is ESM only: Node 12+ is needed to use it and it must be `import`ed instead of `require`d.''
> running the command:

```
$ node --version
v10.19.0
```

so i try to install a newer version of node
but it fails:

```
~$ curl -fsSL deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash - ## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 12.x repo... ## Populating apt-get cache... + apt-get update E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list (Component) E: The list of sources could not be read. Error executing command, exiting –
```

any help?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: I see `nodejs` in version 12.22 available for later release(s), but the version you are using is what is supported in Ubuntu repositories for your 20.04 release (ie. 2020-April product).

Comment: i should be able to update to a newer nodejs from other repos. isn't this right?

Comment: Wait for answers (as has appeared) from other users.. I don't use `nodejs` so I won't provide details on fixes there; I answered on the 'why' isn't it there or "*already the newest version*" part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please open URL: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

For example, to install NodeJS 17+, you can follow the below instructions

```bsh
# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And given URL containes more helpful information. I would suggest going through it.

Thanks.

Comment: mee@mee-Inspiron-3543:~$ curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 12.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Error executing command, exiting

Comment: @StamatisDiamantopoulos Its a different issue. Generally if you could google, you will figure it out.